# Redirect from Visualforce to Service console

Tags: case, console, service

I have a quick Action button which is overridden with vf page on Case feed. Once I fill all the information and click Submit, it gets redirected to standard case feed record page instead of staying on Service console.

I call the following javascript method in action function:

```
oncomplete="Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name : 'publisher.refresh',  payload :  {refresh: true }});"
```

I also tried the following but it does not work.

```
oncomplete="Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name : 'publisher.refresh',  payload :{refresh: "true" objectRelatedLists: {}}});"
```

I want to stay on Service console. Any help much appreciated.